# Select values from one table based on specific value of another table Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have 2 tables:

```
            Location
 id  | user_id | latitude | longitude|
  1  |    2    | 11.32323 | 11.32323 |
  2  |    3    | 12.32323 | 12.32323 | 
  3  |    4    | 21.32323 | 12.32323 |
```

---

```
           Task
 id  | user_id | status |
  1  |    2    |   0    |
  2  |    2    |   1    |
  3  |    2    |   0    |
  4  |    2    |   2    |
  5  |    2    |   1    |
  6  |    2    |   0    |
  7  |    3    |   1    |
  8  |    3    |   1    |
  9  |    3    |   1    |
```

I want to select all rows from location table in which users have

- either no record in Tasks table *(for e.g. user_id = 4)*
- or if records
  exists then all of them **must** have status equals to 1 *(for e.g. user_id
  = 3)*.

In above example, user_id = 2 should not be selected because it has rows in Tasks table with status other than 1.

I am not very much familiar with SQL and LINQ so any help would be appreciated.

This is the expected result:

```
            Result
 id  | user_id | latitude | longitude|
  2  |    3    | 12.32323 | 12.32323 | 
  3  |    4    | 21.32323 | 12.32323 |
```

- Location with user_id = 2 was **ignored** because it has some rows in Tasks table with status other than 1.
- Location with user_id = 3 was **selected** because all rows in Tasks table has status = 1.
- Location with user_id = 4 was **selected** because there were no rows in Tasks table with user_id = 4.

Comment: Can you show your entity classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at you requirements could be this

```
select * from location 
where user_id not in (select distinct user_id from task )
or user_id not in  (select distinct user_id from  task where status != 1);
```

Comment: No actually this will select user_id = 2 too because it has records with status = 1 in tasks table.

Comment: update your question and based on the sample you proived  show a clear expected result  .... anyway i have update the answer

Comment: See the updated question. Added expected result with explanation for selection of records. Plus not necessarily but I would be very grateful if you could answer using linq query.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. The only thing I added on my case was "user_id IS NOT NULL" WHERE clause at the end of both sub queries because user_id column was nullable in Tasks table(which I forgot to mention in question). :)

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are equivalent to saying that no non-"1" value exists in `task`.  I would write this as:

```
select l.*
from location l
where not exists (select 1 from tasks where t.user_id = l.user_id and t.status = 1);
```

I prefer `not exists` to `not in` because `not in` will filter out *all* rows if `user_id` is ever `NULL`  in `tasks`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` without a sub-`SELECT`:

```
SELECT
   l.id,
   l.user_id,
   l.latitude,
   l.longitude
FROM
   Location l
      LEFT JOIN Task t
         ON l.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE
      t.id IS NULL  /* No record in tasks table */
  OR (t.id IS NOT NULL AND l.status = 1) /* if records exists then all of them must have status equals to 1 */
```